# Как определить fps сайта при скроле?

Tags: javascript

При прокрутке на мобильном телефоне, в основном на яндекс браузере, сайт притормаживает. Как определить какой fps и что именно его так тормозит?

Ссылка на сайт: [ссылка](https://www.tvtshop.ru/for-man)

Comment: [google-chrome - how to enable fps counter](https://superuser.com/a/1436133/761205)

Answer (score -1):

Маленький класс для работы именно с FPS.

```js
class Engine {
  static #FPS; // Количество кадров в секунду (тот самый FPS)
  static get FPS() { // в геттер пишем, чтобы был только читабельным
    return this.#FPS;
  }
  static { // Логика расчетов
    let previousFrame = performance.now(); // Момент выполнения предыдущего кадра
    setInterval(() => {
      let currentFrame = performance.now(); // Момент выполнения текущего кадра
      this.#FPS = (1000 / (currentFrame - previousFrame)); // Считаем количество
      previousFrame = currentFrame; // После расчетов текущий кадр становится предыдущей
    }, 0);
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  document.body.innerText = Engine.FPS.toFixed(0);
}, 1000); // Расчеты выполняются часто, но показатель обновляется в каждую секунду
```

---

Для вывода во время прокрутки используйте:

```js
document.addEventListener(`scroll`, (event) => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(Engine.FPS);
});
```

Comment: Как альтернатива, можно использовать `window.performance.now()` вместо `Date.now()`. Он для подобных целей и был разработан

Comment: @SiRanWeb, спасибо, не знал об этой функции. Теперь точнее работает. Но предполагаю что медлит из-за точности.

Comment: И верно предполагаете) Глянул [бенчмарки](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7851/0/datenow-vs-new-dategettime-vs-performancenow), действительно работает помедленнее. Но в контексте задачи это маловажно